# @Value not visible inside @component filter during tests

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, mockito

I created filter which logging and saving all requests, this is part of this:

```
    @Component
    public class RequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

         @Value("${app.endpoint}") 
         private String requestMapping;

        private final RequestRepository requestRepository;

        @Autowired
        public RequestFilter(RequestRepository requestRepository) {
            this.requestRepository = requestRepository;
        }
....
    }
```

When app is running `requestMapping` is properly readed from spring context, but
when I created test for that filter requestMapping is null

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(connection = EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.H2)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyApplication.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class FilterTest  {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private RequestRepository requestRepository;

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        RequestFilter rpmRequestFilter = new RequestFilter(this.requestRepository);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .addFilter(invalidVpmRequestFilter)
                .build();
    }

}
```

And of course in application-test.properties I have configured this property:

```
app.endpoint=/log/save
```

Does someone know where the problem can be? Why this is doesnt work in tests?

Comment: It works like it should work. You are creating a new instance of the filter yourself, instead of letting Spring manage the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M. Deinum pointed out, the problem is that you are creating an instance of `RequestFilter` and if you want Spring to inject components (`@Autowired`) or propoerties (`@Value`) in it, you have to let Spring handle the instantiation as follow :

```
@....
public class FilterTest  {
  ....
  @Autowired
  RequestFilter requestFilter;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .addFilter(requestFilter)
            .build();
  }
}
```